# Motivation for using $\sigma_{8}$?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Press-Schechter formalism allows one to universally quantify the number of massive dark matter halos in a given volume -- **The Halo Mass Function**. The density contrast is given by the rms mass variance in Fourier space, which is the dependent on the linear power spectrum $P_{\rm lin}(k,z)$ in a smooth window $\widetilde{W}(R;k)$
\begin{align}
\sigma^{2}(R,z) 
= \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} dk\ k^{2} P_{\rm lin}(k,z) \left| \widetilde{W}(k;R)\right|^{2}
\end{align}

The halo count can be scaled via observations in a defined window region of $R = 8\ h^{-1}\rm Mpc$. We can solve for this analytical/numerically and measure it from CMB fluctuations, given by the parameter $\sigma_{8}$. The power spectrum, as well as the halo mass function, is then scaled through the normalization of the analytical variance and the observed variance.

My question is then, *why do we choose a smoothing radius of* $R = 8\ h^{-1}\rm Mpc$? Is it arbitrarily chosen to compute the number variance in a cluster, or is their more too that? What prevents me from defining the window radius of $R = 6\ h^{-1}\rm Mpc$ (just ignore the fact that the  WMAP and PLANCK results give $\sigma_{8}$ in the radius of $8$)?

Comment: Mo, Bosch, & White discuss in Cha. 6 various statistical measures that can be used to probe the power spectrum, and write that some are better suited for normalizing the linear power spectrum than $\sigma_8$. But they also write that the amplitude of a power spectrum usually is represented by $\sigma_8$, "largely for historical reasons". My guess is that 6 or 10 would be just as fine, but 0.8 or 80 would be so small/large that the variance would be inconveniently large/small.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Right, I was also thought that is is used for some convenience. I also heard before from my undergrad advisor that it is chosen for "historical reasons"... but that doesn't seem like a very fulfilling reasoning in either case.

Comment: Astronomy, and physics in general, is full of conventions that stick for historical reasons 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific radius of $8 h^{−1} \text{Mpc}$ is used because the value of $\sigma_8$ turned out to be close to unity. To quote e.g. from Amendola & Tsujikawa (2010), p. 39:

> If the cells have a radius of $8 h^{−1} \text{Mpc}$, it turns out that $\sigma_R$ is close to unity. Conventionally the normalization of the power spectrum is therefore given by quoting $\sigma_8$.

Comment: That seems plausible! +1